# Rest Web Service returning 404 Error

Tags: java, rest, web, service, jersey

I am trying to learn simple restful web services. So, I looked up an example and followed it step by step but I am stuck with Error 404 when trying to deploy the project. Any idea why?

File: web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
        id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>UserManagement</display-name>
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
             <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
             </init-param>
          </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>  
    </web-app>
```

File: User.java:

```
    package com.tutorialspoint;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "user")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String profession;

        public User(){}

        public User (int id, String name, String profession){
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.profession = profession;
        }

        public int getID(){
            return id;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setId (int id){
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getProfession(){
            return profession;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setProfession(String profession){
            this.profession = profession;
        }
    }
```

File: UserDao.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UserDao {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        List<User> userList = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("Users.dat");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                User user = new User(1, "Mahesh", "Developer");
                userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                userList.add(user);
                saveUserList(userList);
            }
            else {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                userList = (List<User>) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userList;
    }

    private void saveUserList(List<User> userList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            File file = new File ("User.dat");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (file);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream (fos);
            oos.writeObject(userList);
            oos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

File: UserService.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {

    UserDao userDao = new UserDao();

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userDao.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

Here's what I am getting back 
[Error 404 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AjDI.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change you web.xml file. There is some problem with webxml file. Use this web.xml file use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>User Management</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.tutorialspoint</param-value>
       </init-param>
   </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the possibility that your application is not even deployed (also 404):

The path you configured your rest service to answer is

`<Your application context>/rest/UserService/users`

`<Your application context>` seems to be `/UserManagement`.

- `/rest` is configured in your `web.xml` in the jersey servlet mapping
- `/UserService` is configured in your `UserService.java` file in the `@Path` annotation
- `/users` is configured in `UserService.java` file on the method's `@Path` annotation. This should be `@Path("users")`.

Your screenshot shows you are calling `/UserManagement`, which may be the context of your application, but is not the path to your service.

Comment: I ran it on a server in STS. Also, tried /rest/UserService/users but still no luck

Comment: What is STS? Spring Tool Suite? Did you try `/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users`?

Comment: You should have a look in the logfile. The jersey engine will tell you about the resources found and what URI has been assigned.

Comment: This is what I got from file:
\UserManagement\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: can you see jersey looking for services? and what if you call UserManagement/rest?

Comment: i removed the servlet api from the web-inf lib since tomcat uses its own. however, cant get rid of second error: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.